# APIM - validate-content on consumption tier

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I recently changed our APIM instance from the developer tier, to the consumption tier, and am seeing some weird behavior in the validate-content policy. On the developer tier, this policy would work as expected and return a 400 error with the appropriate error message.

Below is the policy:

```
<validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent">
   <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" />
</validate-content>
```

Below is an example from the trace and the response from developer tier (expected behavior):

```
//Trace
validate-content (0.100 ms)
    {
    "name": "application/json",
    "type": "RequestBody",
    "validationRule": "IncorrectMessage",
    "details": "Body of the request does not conform to the definition skills-POST-request, which is associated with the content type application/json. Property 'nam' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties. Line: 1, Position: 7",
    "action": "Prevented"
}

//Response
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
vary: Origin
    {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Body of the request does not conform to the definition skills-POST-request, which is associated with the content type application/json. Property 'nam' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties. Line: 1, Position: 7"
}
```

However, now the same policy on the consumption tier returns the following trace and response (incorrect behavior):

```
//Trace
validate-content (4.736 ms)
    {
    "name": "application/json",
    "type": "RequestBody",
    "validationRule": "IncorrectMessage",
    "details": "Body of the request does not conform to the definition skills-POST-request, which is associated with the content type application/json. Property 'nam' has not been defined and the schema does not allow additional properties. Line: 1, Position: 7",
    "action": "Prevented"
}
validate-content (0.714 ms)
    {
    "name": null,
    "type": "RequestBody",
    "validationRule": "ValidationException",
    "details": "Body of the request cannot be validated for the content type application/json. Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: key",
    "action": "Prevented"
}
validate-content (2.679 ms)
    {
    "messages": [
        "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: key"
    ]
}

//response
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
vary: Origin
    {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error",
    "activityId": "b3d76aed-fdf0-4240-a5c1-db49fed82105"
}
```

This looks to be some sort of bug perhaps in the content validation policy for the consumption tier?

Comment: As you have already started this discussion on Microsoft Q&A, posting the link here to help other community members: [validate-content policy on consumption tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/657930/validate-content-policy-on-consumption-tier.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I entered a support request with Microsoft and they determined this was a bug in API management. The workaround was to add the following to policy:

```
errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation"
```

So the final policy now looks like:

```
<validate-content unspecified-content-type-action="prevent" max-size="102400" size-exceeded-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestBodyValidation">
   <content type="application/json" validate-as="json" action="prevent" />
</validate-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-features),Consumption tier in APIM supports TLS Settings,External Cache,Client Certificate authentication & Graph QL API's only. Therefore validate-content APIM policy doesn’t work for APIM Services running on consumption SKU.

Comment: How do those features you list relate to the validate-content policy? It's not clear to me the relation between the feature differences and the policy limitations.

Comment: Policies *are* covered in ALL SKUs per the article linked. The only two policies that are not covered in consumption are rate limit by key and quota by key.